# Conditioning pixelsnail on classes

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conditional-statements, one-hot-encoding

I am trying to condition a pixelcnn model that I adapted, but there is needed some changes to condition the model on classes (series). I am working with time-series so in fact I would like to know how could I condition the model in some series as well. But the case, when I try to one hot encode my "Y"`[batch,]` labels that I am giving to it as an array of the same batch length that "X" `[batch, sqrt(seq_len), sqrt(seq_len), channels]`. To condition the model, I have the next code:

```
if args.class_conditional:
    # raise NotImplementedError
    num_labels = train_data.get_num_labels()
    y_init = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(args.init_batch_size,))
    h_init = tf.one_hot(y_init, num_labels)
    y_sample = np.split(
             np.mod(np.arange(args.batch_size), num_labels), args.nr_gpu)
    h_sample = [tf.one_hot(tf.Variable(y_sample[i], trainable=False), num_labels)
             for i in range(args.nr_gpu)]
    ys = [tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(args.batch_size,))
             for i in range(args.nr_gpu)]
    hs = [tf.one_hot(ys[i], num_labels) for i in range(args.nr_gpu)]
  else:
    h_init = None
    h_sample = [None] * args.nr_gpu
    hs = h_sample
```

The current output of "**y_sample**" that is where the shell is locating me the error:

```
[array([0.        , 1.        , 0.30521799, 1.30521799, 0.61043598,
       1.61043598, 0.91565397, 0.22087195, 1.22087195, 0.52608994,
       1.52608994, 0.83130793, 0.13652592, 1.13652592, 0.44174391,
       1.44174391, 0.7469619 , 0.05217988, 1.05217988, 0.35739787,
       1.35739787, 0.66261586, 1.66261586, 0.96783385, 0.27305184,
       1.27305184, 0.57826983, 1.57826983, 0.88348781, 0.1887058 ,
       1.1887058 , 0.49392379, 1.49392379, 0.79914178, 0.10435977,
       1.10435977, 0.40957776, 1.40957776, 0.71479575, 0.02001373,
       1.02001373, 0.32523172, 1.32523172, 0.63044971, 1.63044971,
       0.9356677 , 0.24088569, 1.24088569, 0.54610368, 1.54610368])]
```

it is giving me an error in **h_sample** when it is going to do the one_hot

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 398, in <module>
    main(FLAGS)
  File "train.py", line 111, in main
    for i in range(args.nr_gpu)]
  File "train.py", line 111, in <listcomp>
    for i in range(args.nr_gpu)]
  File "/home/proto/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 2364, in one_hot
    name)
  File "/home/proto/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 2831, in _one_hot
    off_value=off_value, axis=axis, name=name)
  File "/home/proto/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 609, in _apply_op_helper
    param_name=input_name)
  File "/home/proto/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 60, in _SatisfiesTypeConstraint
    ", ".join(dtypes.as_dtype(x).name for x in allowed_list)))
TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'indices' has DataType float64 not in list of allowed values: uint8, int32, int64
```

I changed `for i in range(args.nr_gpu)]` hard-coded to 1 to see if it was the problem but it keeps giving me errors.